# Efficiently determine elements in list should be removed

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I am making a chat-room application on Android. In the application, every 5 seconds, it will send a request to sever for a list of connected users and puts them as `Button`s to a panel. How can I Efficiently  determine if the user is disconnected(if it should be deleted from the list)?

try1:

> Have 2 list, one stores current interval of online list, two stores next interval of online list. Then compare .... O(n^2) comparasions and 2n memory;

try2:

> Have 1 list, each interval deletes  all `Button` in the panel, and recreate them each interval.

They both seem like an ugly solution. Any advice?

Comment: Try something like a `TreeMap`. btw, "premature optimization is the root of all evil".. :-)

Comment: Why are you worried about optimizing this so much? It sounds very trivial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two lists are sorted, we can compare them in O(n) time. Thus, I recommend you to sort lists first (in O(nlogn) time) and compare them later. Hopefully, the server returns lists in order (possibly by the time users log on), you can just compare without sorting.